# Missing wiring in CCheckListBox?

Tags: checkbox, mfc

I can't seem to programmatically query whether a check box is checked or not.

Using Visual Studio's GUI Builder I dragged a "Check Box" from the Toolbox to my dialog.  In Properties Editor I gave it an ID of `IDC_MY_CHECK`.  It's just one check box, not a list of check boxes.

In my controller, in the callback for pushing a submit button I have the code

```
CCheckListBox* myChk = (CCheckListBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_MY_CHECK);
int state = myChk->GetCheck(0)
```

I run it and check the box and click the submit button, but state is 0.

Did I wire it up incorrectly, or is a "Check Box" in the GUI editor not a CCheckListBox the way I think it is?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  It's not a CCheckListBox at all.  It's a CButton.

```
CButton* myChk = (CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_MY_CHECK);
int state = myChk->GetCheck()
```

works.

Comment: This can be simplified: [`int state = IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_MY_CHECK)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa249411(v=vs.60).aspx).